# Split - transform - aggregate

Tags: mule

I'm trying to write test application using twitter connector.
The flow is next:

1. Load retweets;
2. Here I'm getting a list of retweets and I want to transform them one by one. I'm using **for-each**, but earlier I used **collection-splitter**.
3. How I understand, outside foreach block I should have already transformated payload, but in this place I'm getting the same result as at the beginning.

Here is my flow:

```
<flow name="twits">
    <http:listener config-ref="HTTP_Listener_Configuration" path="/twits" doc:name="HTTP"/>
    <twitter:get-retweets statusId="111111111111" config-ref="Twitter" doc:name="Twitter"/>
    <foreach>
        <transformer ref="ReTwitTransformer"/>
    </foreach>
    <json:object-to-json-transformer doc:name="Object to JSON"/>
</flow>
```

So the problem is **at 3 step**, I can't set transformed data into message payload. I already had tried to use **set-payload**  but without success.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [Foreach scope](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/foreach) returns the *original message* after processing each element.  Your transformations will not be retained.

In this case, you might try the [Batch Processing](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/batch-processing) module (EE) or just use a [Collection Splitter](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/routers#collection-splitter) (CE) as you tried previously.

Also, I noticed you're using an HTTP listener to start things off.  If you actually need the collection of transformed retweets back as an HTTP response, you'll have to add a bit more:

If you use the Batch module, you'll need to pair it with a [Request Reply](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/request-reply-scope) router in order to get the collection of successful records back synchronously.  Just put a [Batch Execute](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/routers#collection-aggregator) for the Request, and a VM inbound endpoint for the Reply. Then just put a VM outbound endpoint in the Batch On Complete step.

If you use a Collection Splitter, you'll need a [Collection Aggregator](https://docs.mulesoft.com/mule-user-guide/v/3.7/routers#collection-aggregator) after the transformation occurs.  You might wait until after aggregation to do the object-to-json-transformer.

Comment: Hi, thanks for your answer. One more question about Collection Splitter. When I used it, I'm getting some error, and the only thing helped me, is <async> block. So should I use <async> with collection aggregator at the end of my flow?

Comment: I don't think the async is necessary. What was the error?

Comment: Oh, you are totally right, It works without async, but with combination of splitter-aggregator. Thanks, a lot :)